# EditText inside ExpandableListView is not expanding the childs

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistadapter

I have created an `ExpandableListView` following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ which is working fine. There have 2 `TextView` in the parent group. But when I am adding an `EditText` in parent group it's showing in the `listview` but after clicking on the parent it's not expanding. I assume it's due to the `focus` on `EditText`.

Please help to find a way to `focus` on parent item so that by clicking it expands and shows child items. On the other hand when I will try to write something in `EditText` it should focus on that without expanding the `ListView`.

Here is my code:

```
package com.sifb.icms.sit.application.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.sifb.icms.sit.R;
import com.sifb.icms.sit.object.Object_CateringMenu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter_CateringMenu extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<Object_CateringMenu> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, String> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter_CateringMenu(Context context, ArrayList<Object_CateringMenu> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, String> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).getCategoryChoice());
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cateringmenu_description, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Object_CateringMenu objGroup = (Object_CateringMenu) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cateringmenu, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeaderCat = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryChoice);
        lblListHeaderCat.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeaderCat.setText(objGroup.getCategoryChoice());

        TextView lblListHeaderRatio = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvRatio);
        lblListHeaderRatio.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeaderRatio.setText(objGroup.getRatio());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/svParent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/tvTitleText"
        android:text="@string/cateringmenu_title" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include_cateringmenu_header"
        layout="@layout/list_cateringmenu_header" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elvCateringMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Parent ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCategoryChoice"
        style="@style/tvCateringMenu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRatio"
        style="@style/tvCateringMenu"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMealUplift"
        style="@style/etCateringMenuMealUplift"
        android:layout_weight="0.3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: :I am also doing the same functionality that you worked on can you please tell me how to retrive the value of each editext(that are inside in expandabel view with textview) on a save button click.